# Mysql error in Magento 2.4 during the authentication

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4

Why do I see this issue below during the installation of Magento 2.4?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

[image: Magento 2.4 MySQL]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because of **MySQL 8**, which by default uses the plugin `auth_socket`. Applications will most times expect to log in to your database using a password, to do it access the MySQL via root user and run this command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

Then try to connect using it:

```
mysql -u root -proot
```

If you are using Docker you can specify it like this example below.

> Make sure that you're not using MariaDB to connect into the DB, check it using mysql --version inside your PHP container.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
db:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: magento
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: magento
```

**I fixed it using `mysql:5.7`.**